# Receber valores de array

Tags: php, array, checkbox, foreach, array-multidimensional

Como recebo os valores desse checkbox?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item[<?php echo $IDCatalogo; ?>][<?php echo $IDItem; ?>]">

foreach( $_POST['Item'] as $key => $n ) {
                print "<p>".$n." | ".$key."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade de criar um array-multidimensional para um checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach( $_POST['Item']['IDCatalogo']['IDItem'] as $key => $n ) {
            print "<p>".$n." | ".$key."</p>";
}
```

Espero que lhe ajude.